# Can not boot ubuntu from LiveCD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

So I've been trying to dual boot ubuntu alongside windows 10 on my MSI ge61 6qf laptop. I burned the ISO to the disk and tried to boot off of it, but every time after I choose install ubuntu on the grub menu, the purple screen with the ubuntu writing and 5 dots appear, the animation of orange and white dots go on for a while, then it just freezes. What can be the problem and how can I fix it? Any help is appriciated.

Comment: That means your system is not compatible with Ubuntu.  Try 16.10 (current version is from Oct 12th) and try it every time a new version comes out as that one contains the newest kernel.

Comment: Alright, I will try that. Though doesn't it seem funny that a 4 months old laptop wouldn't be compatible?

Comment: Nope it doesn't: it's too new.